# Существует ли быстрый алгоритм поиска максимальной цепи в графе?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Здравствуйте. Задача: есть взвешенный ориентированный граф (полно циклов, у каждой вершины 5-20 связей), в нем нужно найти такой путь через все вершины, что бы сумма весов пройденных ребер была максимальной, а каждая вершина встречалась только один раз.

Не сложно догадаться до полного перебора, но меня интересуют графы, в которых около сотни вершин.

Существует ли алгоритм, который может найти такой путь?

Если совсем нет, существует ли быстрый алгоритм, позволяющий найти хоть какой-нибудь путь в графе, проходящий через все вершины только один раз?

Comment: Это у Вас в чистом виде [задача коммивояжера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0), соответственно, смотрите алгоритмы ее решения. Быстрый (полиномиальный) точный алгоритм неизвестен, и более того, неизвестно, существует ли он вообще. Так что, смотрите в сторону приближенных алгоритмов.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такой алгоритм.

Перебор всех вариантов с двумя поправками.

1. Для последующих вариантов убираем те вершины через которые прошли (то есть они уже не будут участвовать в расчёте).
2. Сначала идём не в ширину а в глубину. При переборе может быть разный порядок вычислений, в данном случае мы по очереди просматриваем не варианты разных выходов из одной вершины, а сначала идём вглубь переходя к следующей вершине, и уже если там не прошло то идём в ширь.

Алгоритм должен достаточно быстро найти первый путь, хотя сумма и не будет максимальной, но проходя дальше и ища дополнительные пути, можно будет уже выбирать более быстрые. Даже не обязательно все варианты в результате перебирать, можно какой-то процент обработать, и настолько уже можно будет найти более хороший путь.

Далее есть идеи как можно после нахождения первого пути, достаточно быстро без полного перебора находить более быстрые пути.

Найдя первый рабочий путь, смотрим варианты какие вершины можно в порядке прохождения поменять местами, и какие рёбра, если это ускоряет путь, значит нашли более быстрый (Метод улучшения пути).

Если нужна ещё большая оптимизация то ищем N первых рабочих путей, используя случайные варианты. И уже каждый из путей оптимизируем алгоритмом (Метод улучшения пути). Находим из них лучшее решение.